# Impact of micro jobs when applying for a real job?

Tags: software-industry, applications, student

Micro job sites (like for example fiverr) allow one - for example as a computer science student with programming experience - to offer programming services for low rates.  There are numerous examples of (IMO unethical) offers such as "I'll do your programming assignments".  Assume for this question that we're talking about reasonable offers for e.g. (simple ... it's just 5$ after all) code review.

**Is it possible that offering such micro jobs will have a negative impact when applying for a real job?**  Like, for example, do they give the impression of one "selling oneself cheap"?  Or do the sadly numerous dubious offers that can be found on such sites reflect discredit on oneself?

*Note:* I'm not asking about whether to reference such services on a resume, but about the impact when such services are publicly linked to an applicant.

Comment: I'd appreciate any help with tagging my question appropriately :)

Comment: Dear down voter, please explain how I could improve my question.

Comment: It's certainly a very "junior" attitude and approach.

Comment: @Fattie I'm not sure I understand. What part of this is "junior"?

Comment: @DanielJour Is there a way to publicly share which jobs you have performed? The only negative I could think of is that an employer might wrongly assume that you provided some of the more unethical services (i.e. homework). Adding a note to your resume saying "I did nothing unethical!" just makes it seem *more* likely that you did, IMO.

Comment: It's all about how you spin it in an interview. Talk about it like something positive that helped you develop skills that you will be able to apply to the job you're interviewing for and it becomes useful. Talk about it like you're kind of ashamed of having done it because sometimes the work has negative associations and it becomes a hindrance. Almost anything can be relevant to a new job, you just have to show the interviewer what skills it helped you develop and how those will help you in your new job.

Comment: @DavidK Not prefectly up to date, but here: https://stackoverflow.com/cv/musteresel Though I don't plan on even including this experience in a resume. What I'm asking about is if such experience could be e.g. a red flag to a hiring person when it turns up when she/he googles my name, for example. Should I try to express this concern more clearly in my question?

Answer (score 1):

"Selling oneself cheap" is only negative to some employers, not all, especially considering they are the ones to pay. On the positive side of things, showing it hints that the applicant is someone that like to help and get jobs done, has a business sense, don't overvalue his time, and appreciate his field of work.

I think it will be viewed as a positive thing applying for a subordinate position, but might look odd applying for a more executive position where it can be regarded as a lack of self-esteem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that offering such micro jobs will have a negative
>   impact when applying for a real job? Like, for example, do they give
>   the impression of one "selling oneself cheap"? Or do the sadly
>   numerous dubious offers that can be found on such sites reflect
>   discredit on oneself?

- Explicit price may be an anchor but usually the first time jobs or internships are not highly paid until you get enough experience. You need some starting point.
- Employers usually want people with experience. If your skills
  are relevant to a job application, it will give you advantage. You may
  argue that you can complete related work faster and more
  efficiently.
- A lot of people give programming advices or do code review on Stack Overflow for free. If you have public profile with proofs that somebody paid for it, it may be advantageous and show that you can deliver results.
- If you have been working for a long time with small tasks and small amounts, it may give impression that you don't look for challenges and don't evolve as specialist.

Comment: It definitely raises the question "Why don't you just get a Good freelance job?" there's so much around; if you're a skilled beginner programmer you can get "more real" freelance jobs.  So ....  it's hard to see it as much of a positive.